# 301 htaccess redirect regular expression to elimate folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

my first question here but SO has always been a good resource for me.
I have an issue with a rewrite in an htaccess. I want totally eliminate a folder

url www.example.com/listor/XXX/12345.html

and rewrite to
www.example.com/listor.12345.html

Im tryign to figure out the regular expression to eliminate /XXX/ that is a varible of 3 digits ex: /456/

Comment: listor.12345.html thanks!